# How to store geocoder data in a separate table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, geolocation, rails-geocoder

I have an app with `Photos` and `Locations`.

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
end
```

What i'm trying to do is to auto geolocate (with [geoocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder)) a photo using a `:address` field but i want to store the geolocation data in the `locations` table.

By following the tutorial from github page of this gem, i'm able to store those data in `Photos` table without any complications but i can't even begin to imagine how to move this auto-geolocation magic to the associated table.

What's more, it would be extremely great, if it would be working like a tagging - if provided address is already in `locations` table, script should associate it with new/updated photo. But if there is no such address in the db, it should create a new location record.

Normally i would do it 100% manually by manually geocoding the photo with `before_save` callback but i feel that it's an extremely dirty solution and i believe there is a solution i don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the [Advanced GeoCoding](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/wiki#advanced-geocoding) section of the docs?

I'm using MongoDB, and here's how I've been doing it.

```
#set up my relationship
embeds_one :address_info

#assign the address_data hash to my embedded document
reverse_geocoded_by :coordinates do |obj,result|
  if obj = result.first
    obj.address_info = result.address_data
  end
end
```

You can see what's coming in from the Geocoder's `result` [here](http://rdoc.info/github/alexreisner/geocoder/master/Geocoder/Result)